# C# Array in array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm stuck trying to create array of arrays..
This is what i have for now, i would appreciate if someone could point me to right direction.

I have `.txt` file which has paths to images and each string has desired output separated with `"|"` like so:

```
":\\\img.png|1"
```

I'm trying to create array that has 2 columns and number of imagepaths as rows. Col 0 being a array of flattened rgb values of the image and col 1 being output as int.

I'm getting error from line `Data[i][0] = Flat;`

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int[]' to 'int'"

It might be obvious to more experienced coders here but i cant wrap my head around this.

```
static int[][] CreateDataSet(string DatasetPath)
{
    string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(DatasetPath);
    int[][] Data = new int[Lines.GetUpperBound(0)][];

    for (int i = 0; i <= Lines.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    {
        Data[i] = new int[2];
        string[] StringSplit = Lines[i].Split('|');
        Data[i][1] = Convert.ToInt32(StringSplit[1]);
        int[] Flat = FlattenArray(ImagetoArray(StringSplit[0]));
        Data[i][0] = Flat;
    }
    return Data;
}
```

Comment: `Data[i][0]` is a single `int`, `Flat` is an array of integers - they're different types

Comment: You should consider creating a class with two fields. This allows you to give meaningful names to these fields rather than referring to them by an index into an array.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, no need to create a class if you can use tuples with named fields.

Comment: @dymanoid Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not familiar with that part of C#. In the languages I use, tuples are still indexed by numbers. In many situations, using names instead is more ideal.

Answer (score 3):

In an array, all elements **must** have same type (or at least must be assignable to a variable of the element's type).

You have two options.

The bad one: use array of objects.

```
object[][] data;
```

Now you can put everything in that array, but it will be slow (boxing of value types) and untyped (hard to use and to maintain).

Instead of a jagged array, use tuples.

```
(int[] FlattenedImage, int Output)[] data;
```

That looks a little bit weird, but it's actually very useful. It's strongly typed, it prevents boxing, and it uses nice and modern language features.

Answer (score 1):

The big problem here is you have an `int` and an `int[]`. So the `[0]` index of `Data` must itself be an array, rather than merely an integer. And since the `[0]` and `[1]` subscripts are different types, you're really gonna need a completely different kind of data structure here.

Here's an example using Tuples:

```
static IEnumerable<(int, int[])> CreateDataSet(string DatasetPath)
{
    var result = new List<(int, int[])> = new List<(int, int[])>();

    foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(DatasetPath))
    {
        var lineData = line.Split('|');            
        yield return (int.Parse(linedata[1]), FlattenArray(ImageToArray(lineData[0])) );
    }
}
```

or with linq:

```
static IEnumerable<(int, int[])> CreateDataSet(string DatasetPath)
{
    return File.ReadLines(DatasetPath).Select(line => {
        var data = line.Split('|');
        return ( int.Parse(data[1]), FlattenArray(ImageToArray(data[0])) );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would create a class or a struct to containt the data it would look something like this:

```
class ImageData
{
    public int[] FlatImate { get; }
    public int Number { get; }

    public ImageData(int[] flatImage, int number)
    {
        FlatImage = flatImage;
        Number = number;
    }
}

static ImageData[] CreateDataSet(string datasetPath)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(datasetPath);
    ImageData[] data = new ImageData[Lines.GetUpperBound(0)];

    for (int i = 0; i <= lines.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    {
        string[] stringSplit = lines[i].Split('|');
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(stringSplit[1]);
        int[] flat = FlattenArray(ImagetoArray(StringSplit[0]));
        data[i] = new ImageData(flat, number);
    }

    return data;
}
```